# return value of 'echo'

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

In VBA is there anyway to return the state of 'Echo'?

`docmd.echo`  or `Application.Echo`

Want to know if it's on or off.
I could write a function that set a global variable, but would prefer if there was a direct way to access the 'echo' value.

[Application.Echo method in MS Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-echo-method-access)

Comment: `Application.Echo True` doesn't hurt if it is already `True`, so it's a good rule of thumb to always do this in your procedure exit handler, if you have set it to False anywhere in that procedure.

Comment: I already do that in my exit and error handler. Just need to know for other reasons.

Comment: The short answer is No. I'm not aware of a long answer.

Comment: Well, of all people, you would know. Thanks.

Comment: The use case for this is a routine that temporarily toggles Echo off while controls are refreshed, and at some point this routine is called by another function that has already turned off Echo and you don't want it back on until the calling function finishes.

Answer (score 1):

I found an approach that looks credible in [VBA Alchemy: Turning Methods Into Properties](https://nolongerset.com/vba-alchemy-turning-methods-into-properties/):

> Oct 19, 2020
>
> ...The code to turn screen painting on and off in Access is a method,
> which means there is no way to check its current status.  Writing code
> like the example above is impossible in Access.  How did I handle the
> problem?  I created a class module and wrapped the
> **Application.Echo** method inside a class property.  I used the Singleton pattern (without realizing that's what it was at the time)
> to maintain this piece of program state.  I named this class
> **clsApp** and created a single public instance of the class declared with the **New** keyword so that it would always be available.
>
> Here is an excerpt from my clsApp class...

Comment: The article presents a use-case that corroborates the comment above from @Ben.